# Preview Omniscript as different user?

Tags: omnistudio, preview, omniscript

I have created an Omniscript who's components rely heavily on the current user's id. I am using the environment variable userId. An example of this is use is that I pass userId to a Dataraptor that returns the Contact information for that specific user Id.

I am able to test the different users by signing in as different users and opening up a page where the Omniscript is embedded. However, I would like to test different users in the Preview tab. Is there a way for me to override userId purely when I test the Omniscript?

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered the answer using the ContextId and the always handy Set Values!

I simply set a json key value pair using a the custom formula `IF(EQUALS(%ContextId%, NULL), %userId%, %ContextId%)`

Then I pass the `activeUserId` instead of the `userId`.

So much better for testing other users.

[image: Screenshot of Set Values element, with a formula that uses either the ContextId or the userId]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using a setValues to set the user Id or profile in the beginning of the OS to "force" it to use that user(haven't tested it with a user specifically, but worth the shot).

[image]

Comment: This is something I would encourage you to try first before including in an answer. When you're giving a solution, the burden to show that it works is generally on the person providing the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm not kinda new here but for answers, I am.